# Can I boot a live ubuntu from WiFi?

Tags: boot, wireless, nfs, live-environment, tftp

Some years ago I tried disk-less setups where the host did not have a HD and booted from the net. At that moment it was via cable with an integrated card so the Bios could use it.

Today, I have a PC laptop with some HD data that I would need to manage from inside an Ubuntu acting as a recovery system. I don't want to open the hardware to extract the disk.

So the natural options should be either boot a recovery ubuntu from a CD or from a pen-drive.

But, hey, we are at 2020, not 2005!!! Time elapses.

Booting from CD-ROM seems very obsolete those days, and pen-drives start to seem so too. The 10-year-old kids see CDs and PenDrives (both for data and music) as "an old device" as 20-years-old youths saw diskettes for data cassettes and vinyls for music 10 years ago.

The laptop has an integrated cable-ETH (which I think I never used) and an integrated WiFi.

## Question

I wonder if there's any **easy** way to combine the "disk-less setup" with "Wi-Fi" and with a "live ubuntu" so I can enter in the laptop's BIOS, tell "hey you, boot from X" and boom! done! have the laptop to boot a diskless recovery ubuntu from the WiFi instead of from a CD or PenDrive.

I barely remember how it was... but I think in the 2000's the disk-less setup was a combination of a t-ftp server (I think it was a ip-less ftp server or something like this) and nfs.

NOTE: I control the LAN, I can setup a server in the LAN if needed. I can also use linux and windows tools and/or start docker containers to act as the t-ftp if needed.

Any "standardized" diskless ubuntu boot in 2020?

Comment: Here's [one easy way](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/netbooting-the-live-server-installer/14510) to setup the PXE Boot. Note that this is for server - you can substitute the URL of a Desktop installer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your WiFi connects at power up, with no need for CPU interaction,  and has PXE in ROM, no. Read the Wikipedia pages on "BIOS" and "POST Power On Self Test" and  "PXE".

It all dependent on what starts when, and what can be used to start the next step, on the Long and Complex Journey from **OFF** to **ON**.